# How to open Python-3.5 Idle in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-idle

My OS is Ubuntu.
I downloaded Python-3.5 and confirmed it works.
Then I also downloaded idle-python3.5. But I cannot find a way to execute it.

How can I execute it? 
What I want to do is to execute it and make a new file and save it.

Comment: How did you install Python? How have you tried to run Python/IDLE? You haven't even mentioned *the OS you're using!*

Comment: `python -m idlelib.idle` preceded by `sudo apt-get install idle` if idle is not installed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<python> -m idlelib` in a console should work on any system for any python 3.x.
`<python>` is whatever is needed to start a particular version of python.  On linux, `python3` should load the latest 3.x installed. For 2.7, change `idlelib` to `idlelib.idle`.  There may also be an icon you can use, but that depends on the OS and installation options you select.

For how to use IDLE, see the IDLE chapter in the manual (in the index) or with IDLE running, select Help => IDLE Help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, Start>All Programs>Python 3.5>IDLE

To make a new file, you can use Python's default editor by pressing `Ctrl+N` when you're in IDLE. Then to run that script, you press `F5`.

Comment: Really thanks for your help I should have written my OS..